# Non-looping animations in GLSL shader

Tags: glsl

It's fairly trivial to animate a *looping* value in GLSL.

```
uniform float u_time;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(){
  float val = sin(u_time);
  fragColor = vec4(val);
}
```

A graph of the value of `val` over time looks like this:

[image]

But what if we only wanted to do an animation one, two, or three times? Or arbitrarily trigger some animation when, for example, a user clicks the screen?

So that our graph of `val` would look like this:

[[image: f]

Comment: GLSL is just code. So you write code that does that. As for UI, why do you think it is a *shading language*'s responsibility to respond to user input?

Comment: I guess it just seems difficult to animate something when all we're providing the shader with is the current elapsed time, u_time. So it's not apparent to me how you might say, lerp one value to another over 2000 milliseconds if we only have one universal clock.

Comment: It's your code. You have what you *choose* to have. You don't have to provide "one universal clock". In fact, you don't even have to use the *same shader* for the entire animation.

Comment: simply bound (cut off) the animation parameter by a constant:  `float val = sin(min(u_time,u_animation_duration_constant));`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```c
uniform float u_time;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(){
  float some_time = 2.75 * 3.141592;
  float val;
  if (u_time < some_time){
    val = sin(u_time);
  } else {
    val = -1.0; 
  }
  fragColor = vec4(val);
}
```

Just need to make sure that the time threashold = 0.75 + n * PI for a smooth transition between the sine wave and the straight line